# How to remove all properties that match a regex from a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, regex, algorithm, object

I have the following JS object:

```
let obj = {
    'a': 1,
    'a-gaboom': 1,
    'b': 1,
    'b-gaboom': 1
};
```

I want to delete all fields that end with `'-gaboom'`.

I could do it manually with:

```
delete obj['a-gaboom'];
delete obj['b-gaboom'];
```

But I'd like to do it dynamically using a RegExp?

Comment: The current answers each assume that all `-gaboom`s are at the root.  If you need to turn `{a: 1, b: {'c-gaboom': 2, d: 3, e: {f: 5, 'g-gaboo,': 6}}}` into `{a: 1, b: {d: 3, e: {f: 5}}}` then it will still not be difficult, but is itself an interesting question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it using [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) or [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), even though these will not take into account if `-gaboom` appears at the end of the key or at any other position, or using [`String.prototype.endsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith), which will make sure the match is at the end of the key:

```js
const obj = {
    'a': 1,
    'a-gaboom': 1,
    'b': 1,
    'b-gaboom': 1
};

for (const key in obj) {
  if (key.endsWith('-gaboom')) delete obj[key];
}

console.log(obj);
```

Anyway, this would be how it would look like with a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), which does make sure `-gaboom` is at the end of the key by using `$` and can easily be adapted to be way more flexible than any of the other alternatives above:

```js
const obj = {
    'a': 1,
    'a-gaboom': 1,
    'b': 1,
    'b-gaboom': 1
};

for (const key in obj) {
  if (/-gaboom$/.test(key)) delete obj[key];
}

console.log(obj);
```

If you want to go for something more readable or a one-liner, I'd go for @OriDrori's approach or something similar using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const obj = {
    'a': 1,
    'a-gaboom': 1,
    'b': 1,
    'b-gaboom': 1
};

const filtered = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => !/-gaboom$/.test(key)).reduce((acc, key) => {
  acc[key] = obj[key]; 
  return acc;
}, { });

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the entries (array of [key, value] pairs) of the object with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array of entries, and keep only entries with a key that doesn't end with `-gaboom`. Convert back to an object via [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
const obj = {'a': 1,'a-gaboom': 1,'b': 1,'b-gaboom': 1}

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([key]) => !key.endsWith('-gaboom'))
)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks! @DanZiger got his answer in just 1 min before yours so I have to approve his, but yours also works. Much appreciated!

Comment: Note. That there is a major difference between the methods - mine creates a new object, while @Danziger's mutates the original object. If you need to change to original object, you should use his.

Answer (score 0):

taking a cue from the other answers, with this generic function it is possible to eliminate all the keys that verify a specific condition while mutating the original object.

```js
deleteKeys = function (obj, fn) {
  Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([key, value]) => fn(key, value))
    .forEach(([key]) => delete obj[key]);
};

const obj = {'a': 1,'a-gaboom': 1,'b': 1,'b-gaboom': 1};

deleteKeys(obj, (key) => !key.endsWith("-gaboom"));

console.log(obj)
```